# Edit conditional tabs in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

everything responds correctly...
yet in the embedded interface it only shows an empty field...

```
GET /restapi/v2/login_information
POST /restapi/v2/accounts/ANUM/envelopes
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/ANUM/envelopes/EID/recipients/1/tabs

[see conditional tab... edit the value]
[see parent tab... edit the value]
[resubmit]

PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/ANUM/envelopes/EID/recipients/1/tabs
[status='sent']
PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/ANUM/envelopes/EID
POST /restapi/v2/accounts/ANUM/envelopes/EID/views/recipient
```

editing tabs works only if the tab is not conditional on another tab...
when I say conditional I mean the "Conditional Fields: Parent Tag/Parent Value" settings.

What am I missing?

I want to be able to provide default content in a conditionally required box, but then have it so that if the user clears that box, they won't be able to confirm signing until they provide a new value or change the parent tab.  It's not essential, but it would be nice.

Comment: Are you setting the `locked` property to false (meaning the field(s) are editable) and also the `required` property to true (meaning the field can not be empty) for the tabs you want to be editable and required?

Comment: Yes I am setting locked to false as I want the user to be able to edit the field if they choose.

Comment: Need more info to be able to debug this.  Specifically, please post the JSON you are using to create the conditional tabs.

Comment: i'm using the tabs from a templates document, which is why I am able to GET the tab and then PUT the altered tab values back in.

Comment: ok well we still need more info to be able to help.  If they're from a template then please post the template definition (remove the document bytes if it contains a private document(s) you don't want to share)